# downloadHandler in R Shiny App downloads html file of user interface instead of output of write.csv

Tags: r, shiny

I'm finalizing an R Shiny App. I need to use downloadHandler to download a csv file when the user clicks "download_button" and have gotten this to work locally when run in the Viewer, but NOT externally. Whenever I run my code, downloadHandler downloads the user interface, NOT the generated csv file.

This is the code that works locally.

```
observeEvent(input$download_blueprint, {
      # Get the data from the reactiveValues object
      blueprint_csv <- rValues_merged
      # Create a file name
      file_name <- paste("blueprint.csv", sep = "")
```

However, when this is on RShiny.io, I need it to download to the user's default for browser downloads. So I modified the code to use downloadHandler to generate the csv file.

```
observeEvent(input$download_blueprint, {
      
# Get the data from the reactiveValues object
      blueprint_csv <- rValues_merged
      # Create a file name
      file_name <- paste("blueprint.csv", sep = "")
      # Write the data to the file
      output$download_blueprint <- downloadHandler(
        filename = file_name,
        content = function(file) {
          write.csv(blueprint_csv, file)
        })
```

This downloads an html file of the user interface, NOT the CSV file. This is the first time using downloadHandler, so I apologize if the answer to this is super obvious.

I've also tried using this line of code to bypass problems with disabled elements

And I've tried running it in alternative browsers

Comment: Where is the value of `rValues_merged` being set? If you change `blueprint_csv <- rValues_merged` to `blueprint_csv <- iris` does it still download the html?

Comment: Based on the comment `Get the data from the reactiveValues object`, I wonder if `rValues_merged` should instead be `rValues_merged()`.

Comment: BridgetMcHugh, I've never seen a case where _nesting_ `observe`/`reactive` components in shiny made sense; the closest I've seen to justified is when one does not want the download handler even visible until something else happens, ... but there are better ways to control that without nesting. Move your `downHandler` to the top-level within `server <- function(input, output, session) { ... }`. Since it appears your filename is invariant, setting `filename="blueprint.csv"` should be fine, though I often resort to a function where the filename can change based on reactive data.

Comment: @MrFlick, rValues_merged is the output of several earlier events that I’ve experienced zero issues with. Event 1: the user uploads a csv file, then displays it in the top tab of the main panel. Event 2: user specifies several parameters, then calculates additional variables and displays the output as a data table in the second tab. The user checks the output and hits a button to create rValues_merged, which includes additional calculations and is rendered as a table in the final tab. This process works with the local code but not when I use downloadHandler to download it off the server.

Comment: @r2evans the local code worked. Would () be required for downloadHandler but not the local version of the code, which successfully downloaded the CSV file to the working directory?

Comment: @r2evans unfortunately, rValues_merged is the output of a multistep process that requires user  inputs before it's generated, so the event to download the csv file is  nested within another event in the session code. Also, observeEvent worked when run locally and saved the csv to the working directory. Can you please explain why observeEvent isn't suitable when using downloadHandler?

Comment: All I can say is that I've never seen a time when nesting `observe`/`reactive` blocks was _required_, made sense, or even added any value. I work in shiny and R for a living, and while I'm not a perfect shiny guru, I've been working on and with it enough to at least say "I don't see the value in that". If `rValue`_merged` is a simple R object (not a reactive object), then you could certainly have that data calculation in its own reactive block (e.g., `someval <- reactive(...)`) and then in your download handler rely on `someval()`, and that is how I tend to do it.

Comment: But to be fair, I don't know that it's pure evil, just that it adds complexity that I choose to avoid.